# Android Bluetooth LE ScanFilter

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I like to scan for Bluetooth devices with a filter for the services supported by my device. I've read about a couple problems with scanfilters in Android and was know wondering which method is more stable:

`BluetoothLEScanner.startScan(...)`

or better use the old one:

```
BluetoothAdapter.startLEScan()
```

?

Comment: `BluetoothAdapter.startLEScan()` uses `BluetoothLEScanner.startScan(...)` inside of it (in Android versions after BluetoothAdapter.startLEScan() is deprecated). So there is not much difference

Comment: most of those problems are "features". [Check](https://github.com/iDevicesInc/SweetBlue/wiki/Android-BLE-Issues)

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko that's not really right. `BluetoothLEScanner` was implemented in API 21. You can find `startLeScan()` from API 19. `BluetoothLEScanner` is an upgrade of the `startLeScan()`. Check and change API levels: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/BluetoothLeAdvertiser.

Comment: @margabro, ok, you say that it is not really right. Let's check the sources: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.0.0_r1/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.java#1662 Here is the line of code, where `BluetoothAdapter.startLEScan() uses BluetoothLEScanner.startScan(...) inside of it` as I said.

Comment: In 5.0.0_r1 means you are in API 21, where they implemented the `BluetoothLEScanner` and inserted it in the `BluetoothAdapter` just in case someone else will use it in the future and to unify the methods. However it is specified that `BluetoothAdapter.startLeScan()` it is `Deprecated` and `BluetoothLEScanner` should be used.

NOW, if you go back to the 4.4.4_r1 version (using the yellow arrow to the left), which is API 19, you will not find `BluetoothLeScanner` on the `BluetoothAdapter` class.

Comment: @margabro 5.0.0_r1 is API 21, but I totally understand what you mean, and that's why I wrote `(in Android versions after BluetoothAdapter.startLEScan() is deprecated)` in original comment

Comment: OK many thanks to all. That helps!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`BluetoothAdapter.startLEScan` is deprecated and I only recommend it's usage if you want to support Android versions older than 5.0. (From 4.4 to 5.0). Starting Android 5.0 the `BluetoothLEScanne.startScan()` was implemented and all the BLE library improved and more stable.

Now with tens of applications developed for BLE devices (most of the for beacon devices with both iBeacon and Eddystone protocols) I use the newest `startScan` method and I always try to convince my clients that it is important to start supporting devices with Android 5.0 and above. Easier and faster implementation, and much more stable. And by now they are a around [85% of Android](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/) devices worldwide.

Answer (score 1):

```
BluetoothAdapter.startLEScan()
```

this method is deprecated now used

```
startScan(List, ScanSettings, ScanCallback)
```

Starts a scan for Bluetooth LE devices.

Results of the scan are reported using the

```
onLeScan(BluetoothDevice, int, byte[]) callback method
```

Requires the BLUETOOTH_ADMIN, ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION or ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission.